# htaccess rewriting string.string to argument

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've waste a few hours trying but can't get it working.
I have a /MyFolder folder with index.php and page.php
On the index I want to link to /MyFolder/Bibi.Bobo that would in real call /MyFolder/page.php?a=Bibi.Bobo
I can change the bibi/bobo separator if that's what cause the error.
I have tested on an online rewrite checher something working but it make my server into error500

```
RewriteRule ^MyFolder/([0-9a-z]+).([0-9a-z]+)$ /MyFolder/page.php?a=$1.$2 [QSA,NC]
```

-> /MyFolder/bibi.bobo devient ainsi /MyFolder/page.php?a=bibi.bobo

I would like to avoid the page.php to not create an infinite loop so I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^MyFolder/([0-9a-z]+).([0-9a-z]+)
RewriteRule /MyFolder/page.php?a=%1.%2 [QSA,NC]
```

But doesn't work neither.
Anyone could help solve this with a few explanations why my finding doesn't work ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^MyFolder/page\.php
RewriteRule ^MyFolder/([0-9a-z]+)\.([0-9a-z]+)$ /MyFolder/page.php?a=$1.$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

You could also modify your amtching pattern such that it does not use specifically definend character sets:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^MyFolder/page\.php
RewriteRule ^MyFolder/([^.]+)\.(.+)$ /MyFolder/page.php?a=$1.$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

*Note that obviously there must nor exist a file or folder called like the pattern you try to match...*

If you get an http status 500, then you should check your http servers error log file to see what error actually occurred.

Comment: Works perfecty ! Seems I didn't escaped the '.' then ? \. Still a problem anyway, doesn't work with MyFolder/bébé.bobo dues to accents, I guess they don't match ?

Comment: ok it works with ([0-9áéíóúñÁÉÍÓÚÑäëïöüÄËÏÖÜçÇA-Za-z-]+)\.([0-9áéíóúñÁÉÍÓÚÑäëïöüÄËÏÖÜçÇA-Za-z-]+) but not really nice lol ! Many thanks arkascha !!!

Comment: Sure, those accented characters are _not_ contained in the character set you exclusively defined in your pattern. Question is if you actually _have_ to define such a set... I added such a variant to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, your last pattern works perfectly !! You saved my day, many thanks !

Comment: Glad I could be of help. And I am thankful for my reward in form of you upvoting or accepting the answer :-) Have fun!